# How to resize the mxgraph container and retain the cell position after toggle of cells in tree chart?

Tags: javascript, resize, mxgraph

When setting `overflow:scroll` to have scrollbars instead of panning in treechart, facing strange issues. On folding the top rood node cells, the node going behind outline container and not centre aligned. The outline container is fixed in position and always visible.

Graph.fit is not the option which i am looking for, is there any way i can resize the graph container according to the size of graph?

[image]

Expectation is to call a method, so that the folded cell should be present in the place where it was got clicked or at-least come to the centre and visible.

Answer (score 1):

Not full answer, but if you want to resize graph container, there is [doResizeContainer](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.doResizeContainer) method. It accepts width and height as its parameters

Comment: So graph.getBounds().width and height I can use?

Comment: Partial fix, but this doesn't work on toggle of cell